# What should I do to increase bitcoind sync speed?

Tags: bitcoind, synchronization

My VPS has 2gb RAM and CPU core is 1 and 1 TB HDD storage. The sync speed is very slow. Currently it has about 700 MB free RAM. bitcoind is taking about 66% of the 2GB ram.
Should I add 1GB more RAM or is there any way to get similar improvement using any configuration?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
bitcoind -daemon -dbcache=4000
```

Comment: `listen=1` is not required

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have `listen=1` in your bitcoin.conf file, and that the P2P port is open on your VPS so that it can make more than 8 connections.

Then you'll want to make sure you have a high disk speed or IO specified (definitely not HDD - I have a feeling you meant SSD). The faster the SSD the better. 2GB RAM should be fine, but you may want to up it to 4GB and 4 CPUs, at least while syncing. `bitcoind` will use the most resources while syncing, then you can downgrade once it's synced.

Comment: Adding connections does not speed anything up (generally you only sync from outgoing connections). Adding RAM is likely the most important thing (and equivalently increasing dbcache setting; otherwise more RAM doesn't help).

Answer (score -1):

You can:

- stop bitcoind; download the blocks from another source (there are some through torrent) and copy them to the data directory; You then restart bitcoind and let it go through the blockhain validating everything.
- increase the database cache size with the command line -dbcache. You can increase this to max 4GB. But you'll need a more ram in your system.

Comment: More than 4GB works fine (only on 64-bit systems, of course), and is certainly beneficial.

Comment: `-dbcache=2000` really helped here, although the OP may need to settle for `1200`. Also temporarily stopping other process which were using RAM freed up more RAM for disk cache and dbcache. But dbcache was definitely the most helpful. When the sync is complete, I will remove -dbcache option because it's [not needed](https://forum.bitcoingold.org/t/faq-speeding-up-ibd-a-full-nodes-first-sync/4841).